# How to use an encrypted private key with golang ssh

Tags: go, ssh, x509

I would appreciate pointers because I cannot work out how to decrypt an encrypted key in order to use it with golang ssh. I'm attempting to mash together two other sources of code (including [this](http://kukuruku.co/hub/golang/ssh-commands-execution-on-hundreds-of-servers-via-go) one) but unable to get this to work.

I think I'm getting to a DER but need to marshall this back to PEM in order to use it with crypto/ssh

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,D7C72273BE168626E5B2D1BC72E56326
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I read it:

```
key, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to read private key: %v", err)
}
```

With an unencrypted (!) key, I can then:

```
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to parse private key: %v", err)
}

config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: username,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    },
}
```

And this would work.

I reused some code that I think gets me the decrypted PEM as a DER:

```
func decrypt(key []byte, password []byte) []byte {
    block, rest := pem.Decode(key)
    if len(rest) > 0 {
        log.Fatalf("Extra data included in key")
    }
    der, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Decrypt failed: %v", err)
    }
    return der
}
```

But, how do I get from the DER to a signer?

Or, what's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the DER block with an RSA private key, you use `x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey` to parse the key, and `ssh.NewSignerFromKey` to get the `ssh.Signer`

```
key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(der)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
signer := ssh.NewSignerFromKey(key)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
```

With unencrypted key:

```
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
```

With encrypted key:

```
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKeyWithPassphrase(key, []byte("password"))
```

Then:

```
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: username,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    },
}
```

Comment: Maybe ParsePrivateKeyWithPassphrase() is a new addition to the package. This works if you use the correct package name "ssh" instead of "ssh2".

Comment: Why Auth accept `AuthMethod{PublicKey}`? SSH clients use private key...

Answer (score 7):

I'm just going to provide an alternative here, which allows to reuse the `ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)`. I've modified the `decrypt` function to decrypt and encode the private key, if it is encrypted, and return it, so that the returned `key` can be used directly in `ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)`. It utilizes `pem.EncodeToMemory` to get the key from decrypted PEM block.

```
func decrypt(key []byte, password []byte) []byte {
    block, rest := pem.Decode(key)
    if len(rest) > 0 {
        log.Fatalf("Extra data included in key")
    }

    if x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock(block) {
        der, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, password)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Decrypt failed: %v", err)
        }
        return pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: block.Type, Bytes: der})
    }
    return key
}
```

Comment: I'd change the hardcoded {Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", ...} to {Type: block.Type, ...} because this code snippet will accidentally change the PEM block type if the input block is not of type "RSA PRIVATE KEY".

Comment: Thanks! Made changes to the answer.

Comment: x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock and x509.DecryptPEMBlock shows as deprecated and insecure by design.

Comment: @KarelBílek I saw this too, do you have any alternative way of doing it? If so, could you point me out the right direction?